# Integrate triangle

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

> Suppose $f$ is continuous on $A = \{z : \text{Im}(z)\geq0\}$ and analytic on  $\Omega=\{z :
> \text{Im}(z) > 0\}$. Let $T$ be a triangle in $A$ with one side on the $x$-axis. Prove that
>   $\int_Tf(z) dz = 0$.

I am totally stuck on how to do this.  I know there will be some approximation to $T$ be triangles in the upperhalf plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\epsilon > 0$ let $T_\epsilon = T + i\epsilon$, then $\int_{T_\epsilon} f(z)\,dz = 0$. On the other hand 
\begin{align*}
  \left|\int_{T_\epsilon} f(z)\,dz - \int_T f(z)\,dz\right|
   &= \left|\int_{T} f(z+i\epsilon)\,dz - \int_T f(z)\,dz\right|\\
   &\le \int_T \left|f(z+i\epsilon) - f(z)\right|\,|dz|\\
   &\le C \cdot \sup_{z \in T} \left|f(z+i\epsilon) - f(z)\right|\\
\end{align*}
where $C$ denotes the circumference of $T$. As $f$ is uniformly continuous on $T + [0,1]i$, this converges to $0$ for $\epsilon \to 0$.

Thus $\int_T f(z)\,dz = 0$.

Comment: This is what I was writing.